# Cortex M0 int16 fft same as q15 fft

Tags: signal-processing, fft, cortex-m

I have to write a program that performs an fft on 16 bit data. After looking around the ARM CMSIS DSP library site, I found the arm_rfft_q15 fft. I was wondering if using this function to perform an fft would be equivalent to a 16 bit int real fft.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will perform an FFT on 16Bit input data, it states it clearly on the documentation [here](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/arm__rfft__q15_8c.html)